# softlink to gvim opens regular vim instead

Tags: linux, vim

I have made a softlink inside /bin/ that points from gvim to v, so I can just type `v` in console it would open up gvim.

But instead it opens the regular console version.  How can I make it open gvim instead?

Comment: What wrong with using an `alias` instead of a softlink?

Comment: doesn't work on superuser

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your problem, without success, using the following command:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gvim /bin/v`

You could preferably also use an alias, by adding the following  to `~/.bashrc`:

`alias v="/usr/bin/gvim"`

To apply this change, run:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: doesn't work with super or other users

Comment: I tried the same command but it still opens in terminal, do you get the window with the command bar or a terminal window with vim running inside it

Comment: If you are using a Debian based distro such as Ubuntu, you should try adding the alias to `/etc/bash.bashrc` which works system-wide. Let me know if that works.